# To convert eureka microservice to docker-kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I am converting eureka-microservice to docker-kubernetes.

When I create a `pod`, its getting configuration file on gitlab throught configserver x.x.x.x port 8888 . Got following error :

> Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "https://x.x.x.x:8888/docker/docker": No route to host (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

`x.x.x.x` is an ip address of a configuration server

I have imported Certificate of `https://x.x.x.x:8888` to the image. And created `service.yml` file.

I have created `env` for the docker and created `bootstrap` file as well.

Follow this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-dev/TD4v5710jkQ

I have created `endpoint` for redirect to configserver.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: configserver_name
  namespace: default
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: x.x.x.x
  ports:
  - port: 8888
```

Comment: Have you tried ping from `pod` to the configuration server (x.x.x.x:8888) ?

Comment: Actually, pod die immediately when it start

Comment: That would mean there is something wrong with the image you used.
Can you post the error message with which `pod` died? Also how have you build your `docker` image? As well as please post the yaml files used to deploy the `pod`

Comment: I mean, java app cannot load config file which is place on gitlab throught configserver

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot help without details, please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: just updated the question.

Comment: Have you tested if ping from `pod` to configserver works?